# Kiron 70-201mm f/4 Macro Lens to a Nikon Dslr 3100

Tags: nikon

Is there an adapter/mount I can use to use my film lens (from my old Nikon 35mm camera) on my Nikon Dslr 3100? If so which one should I get? I have several Kiron lenses (made by Kino).

Comment: What model is your old film camera, if it is after mount F (meaning AI, AI-s) it must be compatible with any Nikon D-SLR

Answer (score 3):

If, as I suspect, the lens is an AI or AI-S lens, then you should have no problem using it on your 3100. To determine if it is AI/-S, have a look at the aperture ring.

If you have two aperture scales (numbers going up in increments like 2.8, 3.5, 4, 5.6 etc), with the scale nearest the camera end of the lens in smaller type, you have an AI/S lens and it will work. This should be the case as I believe Kiron only made AI/S lenses for Nikon F-mounts.

Being an AI lens, you should be able to use it in Aperture and Shutter priority modes, but if this doesn't work you can put your camera in Manual mode to get the camera to take photos. It just means a little experimentation/practice with shutter speed in order to get a correct exposure, similar to when you're using a [reversing ring](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/?p=10&preview=true).

Just in case, be very careful attaching the lens to the camera the first time, and if you encounter any resistance, don't force it, to avoid damaging the camera or lens.

Comment: Do you know if a foto diox pro adapter will work to adapt the lens to my Nikon? I've heard it's really good So I was thinking of getting it but want to know if it will work before i buy it and havent been able to find the information. I know it works to attach a nikon lens to a cannon..but that doesnt help me lol

Comment: You don't need an adaptor. The lens and camera both use the nikon F mount so you should be able to just attach it like you would a modern lens.

Comment: Its a little too big for the camera?

Comment: You mean the mount? That's odd.

Comment: yes and I read that I could get an adapter for it that would make it fit onto my d3100 but not sure which to get.